# IIS6 http compression with ASP.NET: is there any disadvantage?

Tags: asp.net

IIS6 http compression with ASP.NET: is there any disadvantage especially when using ajax updatepanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so.I have worked with UpdatePanel for quiet a long time and always IIS Http compression was enabled.Once the page is sent to server during postback then complete page life cycle takes place as if its a normal webpage.During the prerender phase only the markup of content which is inside the ContentTemplate tag of Updatepanel is rendered and sent back to browser.Here in browser that markup is used to update the UI.

Also if you use tools like YSlow and PageSpeed to analyze the performance of webpage then thse tools take Http Comprssion as one of the deciding factor.Enabling compression is one of the prerequistis.

You can check for the extensions which are marked for compression by checking the metabase.xml file in the following location :- Sysroot\Windows\System32\inetsrv\metabase.xml . Rem not to modify the content of this file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that's helpfull.